# Custom post types - Use post_id in permalink structure

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

I'm registering my CPT like so:

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'with_front' => false,
        'slug' => 'news/events'
    ),
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' )
);
register_post_type('events',$args);
```

Now that will generate post permalinks like so: `/news/events/{post_name}/` but I want the following permalink structure: `/news/events/{post_id}/{post_name}/`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Bainternet - your answer didn't fully work but I did some more searching and was able to piece this filter together that did work:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_event_permalink', 1, 3);
function custom_event_permalink($post_link, $id = 0, $leavename) {
    if ( strpos('%event_id%', $post_link) === 'FALSE' ) {
        return $post_link;
    }
    $post = &get_post($id);
    if ( is_wp_error($post) || $post->post_type != 'events' ) {
        return $post_link;
    }
    return str_replace('%event_id%', $post->ID, $post_link);
}
```

+1 for getting me most of the way

Comment: what did you use as slug for cot?

Comment: @Bainternet the slug is auto added to the end by WordPress so there is no need to use `%postname%` otherwise you get the slug twice in the URL

Comment: nice, so you ended up using `news/events/%event_id%/` ?

Comment: yup but without the trailing slash

Comment: What i have to do if i want say adding "blog" before the wordpress default post (no matter what is in the permalink structure on settings).

Comment: **Note:** I have tried `%post_id%` instead of `%event_id%` it seems we don't need the filter, wordpress automatically converts `%post_id%`. Tried with `WP 3.5.1` and Twenty Eleven.

Answer (score 7):

Try this First add to `%event_id%` to your slug:

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'with_front' => false,
        'slug' => 'news/events/%event_id%/%postname%'
    ),
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' )
);
register_post_type('events',$args);
```

then add a filter to the single event premalink:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_event_permalink', 1, 3);
function custom_event_permalink($post_link, $id = 0, $leavename) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $post = &get_post($id);
    if ( is_wp_error( $post )  || 'events' != $post->post_type)
        return $post_link;
    $newlink = $wp_rewrite->get_extra_permastruct('events');
    $newlink = str_replace("%event_id%", $post->ID, $newlink);
    $newlink = home_url(user_trailingslashit($newlink));
    return $newlink;
}
```

that should do the trick but it's **untested**. And make sure to flush rewrite rules.