# How to achieve this permalink -> category-name/custom-post-type-name/post-name

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, rewrite-rules, slug

I am trying to use categories to provide the structure for my site. I will create sections on my site called England, Wales, Scotland and Ireland . These will be categories. My posts will use custom post types - Video, Guide, Event, Clubs etc.

So, if I create a post called 'Trouble down south' using the 'Video' CPT, attach it to the 'England' category, I would like the slug format to be:

**category-name/custom-post-type-name/post-name**

*e.g. mysite.com/england/video/trouble-down-south*

I would also like the following permalinks to work like so -

**mysite.com/england/** - show all posts in that category regardless of CPT

**mysite.com/video/** - show all Video CPT posts regardless of category

Sticking with my example, I create my Video CPT like so:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_video' );

function register_cpt_video() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'videos', 'video' ),

        some code...

    );

    $args = array( 

        some code...

        'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),

        some code...

        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 
            'slug' => 'video', 
            'with_front' => false,
            'feeds' => true,
            'pages' => true
        ),
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'video', $args );
}
```

This almost does what I need. I get the correct listings at

**mysite.com/england** (i.e category archive page)

*and*

**mysite.com/video** (i.e CPT archive page)

Unfortunately when I click through to the actual post, the slug shows as

**mysite.com/video/trouble-down-south**

I would like

**mysite.com/england/video/trouble-down-south**

I've tried using the following rewrite slug

```
'slug' => '%category%/video',
```

This does not work. **%category%** gets literally inserted into the url without being converted into the actual category name.

I have searched this site for a solution but haven't found any. Most related answers seem to address appending taxonomies to the CPT slug.

i.e **mysite.com/video/england/trouble-down-south**

They seem to achieve this by explicitly prefixing the CPT name to the taxonomy rewrite slug which exploits the cascade-like nature of the rewrite rules (plus some other wizardry I don't understand.)

Anyhow, nothing I have found has addressed my requirement of **category-name/custom-post-type-name/post-name**, plus the archive pages I require.

Any ideas how to achieve my desired permalink structure?

Comment: Please add more details to your question: We have many solutions for this on our site (see the related questions in the sidebar). What have you tried, why didn’t it work?

Comment: I've updated my question as per your suggestion. Hopefully it's more clearer now. And yup, I've searched this site for over an hour but most of the related answers address the **CPT/taxonomy/post-name** permalink scheme. I tried wrangling the code I did find to suite my needs, but don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: Well, I spent another hour or so proving to myself that I really need to work on my google-fu. I have failed to find anyone document the permalink scheme I'm trying to achieve. Usually that means I'm going about things the wrong way. Maybe I should try to layout my site structure a different, more WordPress-friendly way?

Comment: **possible duplicate of** [**How to change permalink structure for custom post type and it's taxonomies?**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28979/how-to-change-permalink-structure-for-custom-post-type-and-its-taxonomies)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to filter `'post_type_link'` to create the appropriate permalink. See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/44596/73) for a similar example.

The following code works:

```
add_action( 'init', array ( 'WPSE_63343', 'init' ) );

class WPSE_63343
{
    protected $post_type = 'video';

    public static function init()
    {
        new self;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $args = array (
            'public' => TRUE,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => '[^/]+/' . $this->post_type .'/([^/]+)/?$'
            ),
            'has_archive' => TRUE,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
            'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
            'labels' => array (
                'name' => 'Video',
                'singular_name' => 'Video'
            )
        );
        register_post_type( $this->post_type, $args );

        add_rewrite_rule(
            '[^/]+/' . $this->post_type .'/([^/]+)/?$',
            'index.php?post_type=' . $this->post_type . '&pagename=$matches[1]',
            'top'
        );

        // Inject our custom structure.
        add_filter( 'post_type_link', array ( $this, 'fix_permalink' ), 1, 2 );

        # uncomment for debugging
        # add_action( 'wp_footer', array ( $this, 'debug' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Print debug data into the 404 footer.
     *
     * @wp-hook wp_footer
     * @since   2012.09.04
     * @return  void
     */
    public function debug()
    {
        if ( ! is_404() )
        {
            return;
        }

        global $wp_rewrite, $wp_query;

        print '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars( print_r( $wp_rewrite, TRUE ) ) . '</pre>';
        print '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars( print_r( $wp_query, TRUE ) ) . '</pre>';
    }

    /**
     * Filter permalink construction.
     *
     * @wp-hook post_type_link
     * @param  string $post_link default link.
     * @param  int    $id Post ID
     * @return string
     */
    public function fix_permalink( $post_link, $id = 0 )
    {
        $post = &get_post( $id );
        if ( is_wp_error($post) || $post->post_type != $this->post_type )
        {
            return $post_link;
        }
        // preview
        empty ( $post->slug )
        and ! empty ( $post->post_title )
        and $post->slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes( $post->post_title );

        $cats = get_the_category( $post->ID );

        if ( ! is_array( $cats ) or ! isset ( $cats[0]->slug ) )
        {
            return $post_link;
        }

        return home_url(
            user_trailingslashit( $cats[0]->slug . '/' . $this->post_type . '/' . $post->slug )
        );
    }
}
```

Don’t forget to visit the permalink settings once to refresh the stored rewrite rules.

Comment: Wow, cheers for helping me out. Seems to work as intended. I'll have a go at creating additional cpt's using your code as a template. Many thanks

Comment: Doh, when I use your code example it breaks standard posts and other post types I add categories to. Any ideas why?

Comment: @bob Interesting. See my update: you have to put the rewrite regex into the `slug` parameter. Looks a little bit strange, but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_types' );
function register_my_types() {
    register_post_type( 'recipes',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Recipes' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Recipee' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'country', array( 'recipes' ), array( 
            'hierarchical' => true, 
            'label' => 'Country'
        )
    );
}
// Add our custom permastructures for custom taxonomy and post
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'add_clinic_permastructure' );
function add_clinic_permastructure() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_permastruct( 'country', 'recipes/%country%', false );
    add_permastruct( 'recipes', 'country/%country%/recipes/%recipes%', false );
}
// Make sure that all links on the site, include the related texonomy terms
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'recipe_permalinks', 10, 2 );
function recipe_permalinks( $permalink, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type !== 'recipes' )
        return $permalink;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'country' );

    if ( ! $terms )
        return str_replace( '%country%/', '', $permalink );
    //$post_terms = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $term )
        $post_terms = $term->slug;
    print_r($permalink);
    return str_replace( '%country%',  $post_terms , $permalink );
}
// Make sure that all term links include their parents in the permalinks
add_filter( 'term_link', 'add_term_parents_to_permalinks', 10, 2 );
function add_term_parents_to_permalinks( $permalink, $term ) {
    $term_parents = get_term_parents( $term );
    foreach ( $term_parents as $term_parent )
        $permlink = str_replace( $term->slug, $term_parent->slug . ',' . $term->slug, $permalink );
    return $permlink;
}
// Helper function to get all parents of a term
function get_term_parents( $term, &$parents = array() ) {
    $parent = get_term( $term->parent, $term->taxonomy );

    if ( is_wp_error( $parent ) )
        return $parents;

    $parents[] = $parent;
    if ( $parent->parent )
        get_term_parents( $parent, $parents );
    return $parents;
}
```

**above code paste in theme *function.php* file and change the permalink option `/%category/%postname%/ %`**